# Doctrine2 PostPersist: updating corresponding entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, updating

I have two entities (note that irrelevant methods and properties are omitted):

```
/**
* @Entity
*/
class Manager {

   /**
    * @Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $referencesCount;

    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Reference", mappedBy="manager")
    */
    private $references;

    public functions increaseReferenceCount() {
        $this->referencesCount++;
    }

     // other properties and methods
}


/**
* @Entity
* @HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Reference {

    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Manager", inversedBy="references")
    * @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    */
    private $manager;

    /**
    * @PostPersist
    */
    public function updateManagerReferenceCount() {
        $this->manager->increaseReferenceCount()
    }

     // other properties and methods
}
```

Manager can have many References. One Reference belongs exactly to one Manager. My model should be optimized for queries, so to avoid expensive joins (Manager has much more associations) I add to Manager model $referencesCount property which, you guessed it, holds the numbers of its references. After new Reference is persisted, $referencesCount should be increased. But right now it is not. What am I missing? (I already tired wit cascade={"all"} but it does not work for me)

Comment: Probably you forgot to persist the manager entity after changing it's property, are you?

Comment: Typo maybe?  `@HasLifecycleCallbacs` vs `@HasLifecycleCallbacks`

Comment: @Crisp - no, it's not about a typo :)

Comment: @lazyhammer - I just need it to be done automatically, I mean when I persist Reference object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add [Transitive persistence](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

`cascade={"all"}`

to `Reference` entity (not only for `Manager`).

And replace `@PostPersist` to `@PrePersist`.

Comment: I added Cascade={"all"} to ManyToOne in Reference and OneToMany in Manager - it does not work as I expected.

Comment: Try to replace `@PostPersist` to `@PrePersist`.

Comment: Because the cascades are stored first in memory and executed just before persist.